# WSO2 Identity Server Loses virtual hostname for passivests requests

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I followed [this](http://dulanja.blogspot.in/2015/08/accessing-single-wso2-identity-server.html) link for configuring multiple hostnames for my identity server. Things are working fine and as expected for all samlsso based usecases.

Please note that the actual hostname and management hostname paramter in the carbon.xml is different from the virtual hostname that i give in the apache front end. (Since there are multiple host names)

However when a passivests request comes through one of the virtual hosts it is received by the wso2 identity server with the virtual host and when the redirection happens to the commonauth url the hostname changes to the one which is defined in the carbon.xml file.  so finally when the login page comes up it will be in the format of

Using protocol in lieu of https as I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links. :P

protocol://managementhostname/authenticationendpoint/login.do?commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fpassivests&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=domain1&wa=wsignin1.0

it should have been
protocol://virutalhostname/authenticationendpoint/login.do?commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fpassivests&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=domain1&wa=wsignin1.0

for requests to the /samlsso endpoint it is happening properly with virtualhostname.

It would be great if somebody can throw some light on the issue.

Thanks in advance